# Just created a search bar with html and css, how do I use the same styles for a php search form?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Here is my HTML code for the search bar:

```
 <div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
      <a class ="search-btn" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </a>
 </div>
```

When I delete the HTML and add this php code,

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

The search bar works completely fine in my Wordpress site. However the default styling is very basic, and I want to change this to match my original static search bar.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Wordpress you can create a shortcode that returns your html so it will keep your original HTML style.

[Here](https://speckyboy.com/getting-started-with-wordpress-shortcodes-examples/) you have more information about shortcodes and how to use them to render an HTML element.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

As you can check from template hierarchy here in [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). You have to modify respective templates or widgets from wordpress

In your case you have to override searchform widget, and there are several ways to do it, which is already answered here on [stackoverflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168087/modifying-the-default-search-widget).

Possible Solution would be to carete/override searchform.php in your theme and add your markup on top of that :

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search in <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
    <input type="image" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search.png" />
</form>
```

For More information you can always refer to [get_search_form()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) documentation which has further information on the topic.